# JSON parsing volley with pass two parameters via POST method in android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I want to parsing JSON in android using volleylibrary for login.In Login activity,send two parameters(username,password) via post and response like below.

parameters :

```
username
password
```

for success:

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "successfully login" ,  
        "result": [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "Img": "http://img.com/img.png"
    }      
 ]
}
```

for login:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "email or password doesn’t exist"    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: you should try and do this on your own it's too simple ,don't be lazy and  read the docs.Hint: it's a json object contaning json array

Answer (score 2):

It is how to do it.

```
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                int status = response.getInt("status");
                if (status == 1) {
                  String message = response.getString("message");
                  JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                  String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                  String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                  String imgLink = jsonObject.getString("Img"); 
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is working for me too ... But i recommend to use GSON library for parsing JSON response and it convert it into Java Object here is link of library [link](https://github.com/google/gson) and exmaple to how work with Volley is here [link](http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/11/02/android-parse-json-request-using-volley-gson/)

Comment: Yes, Zohaib you are right. I also use it. But problem is that it seems like he is a naive developer so I thought it would be better to keep thing simple for the sake of better understanding.

Comment: I agree with you, for new developer it is fine to parse JSON with native JSON Api

Comment: Please,give me full code of how to send parameters via post method and response from above answer...

Comment: [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) it contains full example about how to send params with post using volley